# How to use filter in Azure API Management Python SDK

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-sdk-python

Based on the documentation contained in the original [code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/d43554fbeeeb884ab68342fd23166538c3532f67/sdk/apimanagement/azure-mgmt-apimanagement/azure/mgmt/apimanagement/operations/product_operations.py#L39) I try to access API Management and filter for a certain product:

```
    credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
        client_id=clientId,
        secret=secret,
        tenant=tenantId)

    client = ApiManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
    products = client.product.list_by_service(resource_group_name,service_name,filter="displayName eq 'INTERNAL'")
```

which seems valid and according to documentation to me.

However I get this error:

> azure.mgmt.apimanagement.models.error_response_py3.ErrorResponseException: Invalid filter clause specified: 'DisplayName eq 'INTERNAL''.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to inspect the source codes of Azure API Management Python SDK which include [`product_operations.py`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/ab599e7c6c371543e48d210c4a11f163951d83d4/sdk/apimanagement/azure-mgmt-apimanagement/azure/mgmt/apimanagement/operations/product_operations.py), [`error_response_py3.py][1]`, [`msrest-for-python/msrest/serialization.py`](https://github.com/Azure/msrest-for-python/blob/master/msrest/serialization.py), there is not any obvious issue.

Then, after I tried to test the relative REST API [`Product - List By Service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2019-01-01/product/listbyservice) of `ApiManagement.product.list_by_service` function, I discovered the issue may be a bug.

There are six fields can be used in the `$filter` URI parameter: `name`, `displayName`, `description`, `terms`, `state` and `groups`. Except `groups` which I don't know how to feed the corrent expression for `$filter`, I test the rest five fields and only `displayName` does not work.

[image]

The `api-version` value is `2019-01-01`, the json response for `%24filter=displayName%20eq%20%27Starter%27` in my uri parameter is as below.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ValidationError",
    "message": "Invalid filter clause specified: 'displayName eq 'Starter''.",
    "details": null
  }
}
```

So I think it's not your mistake while using Azure API Management Python SDK, it's a bug which seems to be not implemented or other reason.